# How to prove the closed form of the integral $\int \frac {dx}{\prod_{r=0}^n (x+r)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to derive a closed formula for the integral $$I_n= \int \frac {dx}{\prod_{r=0}^n (x+r)}$$

On writing out first few terms we get

For $n=0$, $$I_0=\ln \vert x\vert+C$$
For $n=1$, $$I_1=\ln \vert x\vert-\ln \vert x+1\vert+C$$
For $n=2$ $$I_2=\frac {1}{2!}\left(\sum_{r=0}^2 (-1)^r\binom {2}{r} \ln \vert x+r\vert\right)+C$$
For $n=3$ $$I_3=\frac {1}{3!}\left(\sum_{r=0}^3 (-1)^r\binom {3}{r} \ln \vert x+r\vert\right)+C$$

Hence for generalized $n$ we have $$I_n=\frac {1}{n!}\left(\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\binom {n}{r} (\ln \vert x+r\vert)\right)+C$$

Now this is just an observation but I want to prove that it is correct. I have tried lot of methods but not useful. Partial fractions would have been most useful but would go out on tedious task which is nearly impossible.  Also integration by parts won't help nor any trig substitution. So any ideas are welcome.  And ya,  this is not a homework question,  it's a question which I just saw in a integral challenge paper.

Comment: In fact partial fraction decomposition helps you. You may try Heaviside method in this regard.

Comment: @SangchulLee What is Heaviside method?

Comment: More precisely, it is called [*Heaviside cover-up method*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method), and it works by guessing the form of PFD and determining the coefficients.

Comment: @SangchulLee I just now searched on internet for that method but that would be a tedious task to solve because we will have as much of $n$ unknown coefficient which coincidentally are the binomial coefficients of $n$ starting from $0$.And moreover while finding the coefficients we will have to, a kind of,  use observation that the coefficients are binomial coefficients with alternating signs

Comment: It is not that tedious. All you have to do is write $$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{x+k}$$ and notice that $$c_k = \lim_{x\to-k} \frac{x+k}{\prod_{r=0}(x+r)} = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}.$$ It certainly reduces the amount of labor you have to put in, and this is why the method bears its own name.

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you elaborate a little more on how just wrote $c_k$ in terms of a limit

Comment: The argument is actually easy to understand. Multiply $x+k$ to both sides of $$\frac{1}{\prod_{r=0}^{n}(x+r)} = \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{c_r}{x+r}$$ and let $x\to -k$. In the RHS, only one term, corresponding to $r=k$, survives with the value $c_k$ and the LHS reduces the expression that I wrote above.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks a lot.  What don't you post your comments as answer,  so that I could accept them.

Comment: Actually I remember that similar questions were posted before, which I cannot find right now. Please do not feel discouraged if you find this answer marked as duplicate later.

Comment: @SangchulLee Not at all.  I just posted this question because I was curious to know about its proof.  I also searched on math stackexchange with the hope that someone might have already asked such question but couldn't find it, so thought to ask it myself. Please add a link if you find any related similar question to this one.  Thanks a lot again :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int{\dd x \over \prod_{r = 0}^{n}\pars{x + r}} & =
\int{\dd x \over \Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}/\Gamma\pars{x}} =
{1 \over n!}
\int{\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\over \Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n!}\int\int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t\,\dd x =
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\int t^{x - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}
\bracks{{t^{x - 1} \over \ln\pars{t}} + \,\mrm{A}\pars{t}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}{t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n} \over \ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t +
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}{t^{x - 1}\,\mrm{A}\pars{t} \over \ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{A}\pars{t}}$ is an integration "*constant*" ( it doesn't depend on $\ds{x}$ but, in general, it depends on $\ds{t}$ ).